# Sort Python dictionary by it's keys using another Python list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a `list` of words:

```
['apple', 'zoo', 'chicken', 'needle', 'car', 'computer']
```

I also have a `dictionary` with keys and values:

```
{'zoo': 42, 'needle': 32, 'computer': 18, 'apple': 39, 'car': 11, 'chicken': 12}
```

The keys of my `dictionary` are all from the `list` of words. How can I sort the `dictionary` so that the order of its keys is the same as the order of the words in the `list`? So once sorted, my `dictionary` should look like this:

```
{'apple': 39, 'zoo': 42, 'chicken': 12, 'needle': 32, 'car': 11, 'computer': 18}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Dictionaries don't preserve order. An available ordered version of a dictionary is `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: First of all you should be aware that dictionaries are *un*ordered in Python 3.5 and below. For ordered dictionaries you can use `collections.OrderedDict`.

Comment: @jmd_dk pardon me for hijacking the comment's section for this question, but are dictionaries really ordered in Python 3.6? Looks like I missed that part of the docs then. Nvm found the docs! :)

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar They are indeed. I recommend this nice talk for an overview of the recent (and historic) changes to dicts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npw4s1QTmPg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For python versions < 3.6, dictionaries do not maintain order, and sorting a dictionary is consequently not possible.

You may use the `collections.OrderedDict` to build a new dictionary with the order you want:

```
In [269]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [270]: keys = ['apple', 'zoo', 'chicken', 'needle', 'car', 'computer']
     ...: dict_1 = {'zoo': 42, 'needle': 32, 'computer': 18, 'apple': 39, 'car': 11, 'chicken': 12}
     ...: 

In [271]: dict_2 = OrderedDict()

In [272]: for k in keys:
     ...:     dict_2[k] = dict_1[k]
     ...:     

In [273]: dict_2
Out[273]: 
OrderedDict([('apple', 39),
             ('zoo', 42),
             ('chicken', 12),
             ('needle', 32),
             ('car', 11),
             ('computer', 18)])
```

---

In Python3.6, a simple dict comprehension suffices:

```
>>> {x : dict_1[x] for x in keys}
{'apple': 39, 'zoo': 42, 'chicken': 12, 'needle': 32, 'car': 11, 'computer': 18}
```

Comment: Great, that works! (I'm using 3.6) What if my list has values that my dictionary doesn't? How do I bypass the KeyError without stopping the loop?

Comment: @QuantumJuker You'll need to add an if condition: `if k in dict_1: dict_2[k] = dict_1[k]`

Answer (score 1):

You can used OrderedDict since regular dictionaries are unordered. For your case you could do this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict()

ll = ['apple', 'zoo', 'chicken', 'needle', 'car', 'computer']
d = {'zoo': 42, 'needle': 32, 'computer': 18, 'apple': 39, 'car': 11, 'chicken': 12} 

for f in ll:
  od[f] = d[f]
#Outputs: OrderedDict([('apple', 39), ('zoo', 42), ('chicken', 12), ('needle', 32), ('car', 11), ('computer', 18)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Python dict doesn't preserve order by default, you should use `collections.OrderedDict`. The first item you put into `OrderedDict` is the first item you will get when you enumerate it (e.g. using `for`).

```
from collections import OrderedDict

order_list = ['apple', 'zoo', 'chicken', 'needle', 'car', 'computer']
unordered_dict = {'zoo': 42, 'needle': 32, 'computer': 18, 'apple': 39, 'car': 11, 'chicken': 12}
ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
for item in order_list:
    ordered_dict[item] = unordered_dict[item]

for k, v in unordered_dict.items():
    print(k, v)

for k, v in ordered_dict.items():
    print(k, v)
```